# Apache ProxyPassReverse not forwarding location response

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, proxy, docker

I am trying to forward a subdirectory to a docker setup using Apache proxy and reverseproxy using Apache on a Linux server

Here is the example

```
<Location /foo/>

RewriteEngine On
ProxyPreserveHost Off

proxypass http://docker_host:8233/
ProxyPassReverse http://docker_host:8233/
ProxyPassReverseCookieDomain  "http://Docker_host:8233/"  "https://example.com/foo/"
ProxyPassReverseCookiePath  "/"  "/foo/"

</Location>
```

What ends up happening is that when a `GET` request is sent to `https://example.com/foo/` the docker responds with a `302 Found` and it sends the location as `/welcome/login/`

Then my browser redirects to `https://example.com/welcome/login/` instead of what i am trying to redirect to, which is `https://example.com/foo/welcome/login/`

this ultimately fails in loading the webpage as the resources needed are not pulled.

I followed the apache docs to do this, as listed here:

> path is the name of a local virtual path; url is a partial URL for the remote server. These parameters are used the same way as for the ProxyPass directive.

> For example, suppose the local server has address http://example.com/; then

```
ProxyPass         "/mirror/foo/" "http://backend.example.com/"
ProxyPassReverse  "/mirror/foo/" "http://backend.example.com/"
ProxyPassReverseCookieDomain  "backend.example.com"  "public.example.com"
ProxyPassReverseCookiePath  "/"  "/mirror/foo/"
```

> will not only cause a local request for the http://example.com/mirror/foo/bar to be internally converted into a proxy request to http://backend.example.com/bar (the functionality which ProxyPass provides here). It also takes care of redirects which the server backend.example.com sends when redirecting http://backend.example.com/bar to http://backend.example.com/quux . Apache httpd adjusts this to http://example.com/mirror/foo/quux before forwarding the HTTP redirect response to the client. Note that the hostname used for constructing the URL is chosen in respect to the setting of the UseCanonicalName directive.

> When used inside a  section, the first argument is omitted and the local directory is obtained from the . The same occurs inside a  section, but will probably not work as intended, as ProxyPassReverse will interpret the regexp literally as a path; if needed in this situation, specify the ProxyPassReverse outside the section or in a separate  section.

When looking at the apache docs this exact scenario seems to be accounted for however it is failing, any suggestions?